# Independent clause with no subject

Tags: clauses, imperatives

Like this "Read, write, and think", this is classified as independent clause but they contain verbs only. Is it possible to thave an Independent Clause with no subject?

Comment: If it's an imperative, yes. The _you_ subject of imperatives gets deleted, and that leaves only the verb phrase.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use a subject when creating an "imperative sentence".

"You" is generally omitted, but sometimes it is used.

You (pointing one among multiple people) go. This is an example of an imperative sentence.

If there is only one person in front of you, there is no need to use "you".

Comment: @Caitlin My pleasure.